# Generate Matlab plot markers

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, compression, matlab, octave

Matlab has a useful command for visualizing data: [`plot`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html). It draws data points using "markers" in 2-D space, connecting them with lines; however, for this challenge, let's ignore the lines and use only markers. In fact, only one marker.

Input: one of Matlab's marker symbols: `.` `o` `x` `+` `*` `s` `d` `v` `^` `<` `>` `p` `h`

Output: corresponding image for that marker, which is one of the following 13 icons: [image: markers]

To make it clearer, here are the same icons enlarged, so the pixels can be easily seen:

[image: markers x5]

- Take the input as a string, a `char`, an integer ASCII code, or anything equivalent
- Produce the output by displaying the image, returning it as a function's return value, saving it to a file, etc
- The image should have pixels of two different colours in it. I used blue on white, because this is what Matlab uses by default, but any other colour scheme is OK, e.g. white on black.
- The image can have padding of background colour of any size
- The pixels can be enlarged by any integer ratio, e.g. instead of the original 11-by-9 image for the triangle, you can output a 110-by-72 image, in which 10-by-8 blocks represent the original pixels

  - As a corollary of the above, you can output text with glyphs like `█` instead of an image, if you can print this text properly (i.e. without gaps between glyphs) on the same system which runs the code

---

For quick reference, here are the bitmaps for each input:

- `.`

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `o`

  ```
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `x`

  ```
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  ```
- `+`

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `*`

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `s`

  ```
  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
  ```
- `d`

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `v`

  ```
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `^`

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ```
- `<`

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  ```
- `>`

  ```
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `p`

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  ```
- `h`

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  ```

Any padding with zeros which exists in these bitmaps is optional. So e.g. for the `.` input, a 5x5 image would be sufficient.

Comment: Possibly add [tag:compression]?

Comment: Can output be unpad? (5*5 for `.`)

Comment: Yes. Thought it would be obvious; will clarify.

Comment: Why is the star so horribly mutilated? ergh

Comment: I am more fascinated by the fact that it's still recognizable when the pixels are small enough!

Comment: @JonathanFrech Rather than compression, I think [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] is more appropriate due to the limited number of potential inputs and direct mapping of inputs to outputs (similar to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172716/true-color-code)).

Comment: @Rogem I agree that [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] could fit, however such challenges generally are about constant output and only seldom allow input of any kind. Therefore I suggested [tag:compression].

Answer (score 2):

## [Node.js](https://nodejs.org), 310 bytes

Takes the ASCII code of the symbol as input.

```javascript
n=>Buffer(`~A<<13)$$"~"6+'?'+6"~'81<<<18'~/973202459/~"$$)31<<A~"%;3)3;%"~~ !&(=@=-#! ~""""?""""~"%>3*,:3~~"$))1<1))$"~"'.'"~?<<<<<<<?~1)$"$)1`.split`~`[n*7%86%17]).map(c=>s+=(g=n=>n--?' █'[[...Buffer('$8$$L0$,4$(8(4T(!#""0($,|T8$F'),290,280,34,38,1051].map(c=>p+=c-32,p=0)[c-32]>>n&1]+g(n):`
`)(11),s='')&&s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVHNUoMwEL77FDQNJCkhJYS2tCVgdfTksbeKA5OWVqcCA7XjwcnZJ/ABfZEaRv1mdmf/v93Zl@JcdKp9bk5eVW93l1JeKpncvJXlrsW5XsUxFwRCoMHURSlyp0CjiMcmHCE9ns9E4AfhZD7WAEIiTGKlgb0URCxtoLU1cLC8lt5wYGlgkPbKFCRiRBdCmyZCeMwJ6QkQQ0Cn8S9SzU0QEp6zrjk@n3Kdb6rRzI6mNp9lhL0WDVYy6VyJ99JsXHleiqzvr0@02TDG/g5AMILwwYc0hDjC4RoPhgD4GNKPdQTvEaHB3KdB5FMRUhFR7k949j@6caXyREAb6ZNNb2VJUjk8c/e4Iov8KieYc0I7iRBxnO6y7HkBq9/dUbc9P8VJcwAZK@v2rlAHrCyZWKquuvq4Y8d6jxFAlmspIwgsHqveKbFi6lC0t@YRqxMmBpcf)

#### How?

All symbols can be generated by combining \$34\$ distinct binary patterns.

Each pattern is identified with a character \$C\$ (from space to "A").

The patterns are ordered from lowest to highest, using their decimal representation \$N\$. What's actually stored is the difference \$d\$ between two consecutive patterns, plus \$32\$.

```
 ID |  C  | pattern     |    N |    d | d+32
----+-----+-------------+------+------+------
  0 | ` ` | 00000000100 |    4 |    4 |   36
  1 | `!` | 00000011100 |   28 |   24 |   56
  2 | `"` | 00000100000 |   32 |    4 |   36
  3 | `#` | 00000100100 |   36 |    4 |   36
  4 | `$` | 00001010000 |   80 |   44 |   76
  5 | `%` | 00001100000 |   96 |   16 |   48
  6 | `&` | 00001100100 |  100 |    4 |   36
  7 | `'` | 00001110000 |  112 |   12 |   44
  8 | `(` | 00010000100 |  132 |   20 |   52
  9 | `)` | 00010001000 |  136 |    4 |   36
 10 | `*` | 00010010000 |  144 |    8 |   40
 11 | `+` | 00010101000 |  168 |   24 |   56
 12 | `,` | 00010110000 |  176 |    8 |   40
 13 | `-` | 00011000100 |  196 |   20 |   52
 14 | `.` | 00011111000 |  248 |   52 |   84
 15 | `/` | 00100000000 |  256 |    8 |   40
 16 | `0` | 00100000001 |  257 |    1 |   33
 17 | `1` | 00100000100 |  260 |    3 |   35
 18 | `2` | 00100000110 |  262 |    2 |   34
 19 | `3` | 00100001000 |  264 |    2 |   34
 20 | `4` | 00100011000 |  280 |   16 |   48
 21 | `5` | 00100100000 |  288 |    8 |   40
 22 | `6` | 00100100100 |  292 |    4 |   36
 23 | `7` | 00100110000 |  304 |   12 |   44
 24 | `8` | 00110001100 |  396 |   92 |  124
 25 | `9` | 00111000000 |  448 |   52 |   84
 26 | `:` | 00111011000 |  472 |   24 |   56
 27 | `;` | 00111011100 |  476 |    4 |   36
 28 | `<` | 01000000010 |  514 |   38 |   70
 29 | `=` | 01100000100 |  772 |  258 |  290
 30 | `>` | 01111111100 | 1020 |  248 |  280
 31 | `?` | 01111111110 | 1022 |    2 |   34
 32 | `@` | 10000000100 | 1028 |    6 |   38
 33 | `A` | 11111111111 | 2047 | 1019 | 1051
```

The 29 first values \$d+32\$ can be directly converted to ASCII characters and stored as a Buffer. The last 5 ones are stored as number literals.

```javascript
[...Buffer('$8$$L0$,4$(8(4T(!#""0($,|T8$F'),290,280,34,38,1051]
```

Using the characters \$C\$ defined above, we can encode each symbol as a string.

*Example:*

```
..█........     00100000000 --> '/'
..███......     00111000000 --> '9'
..█..██....     00100110000 --> '7'
..█....█...     00100001000 --> '3'
..█.....██.     00100000110 --> '2'
..█.......█ --> 00100000001 --> '0' --> '/973202459/'
..█.....██.     00100000110 --> '2'
..█...██...     00100011000 --> '4'
..█..█.....     00100100000 --> '5'
..███......     00111000000 --> '9'
..█........     00100000000 --> '/'
```

All symbols are stored in a single string, delimited with `~`. We use a hash function to convert the input ASCII code into the position of the symbol in the list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>163</s> <s>154</s> 152 bytes

```
≔█η≡θo«Ｇ→↘→²η‖Ｏ↘¬»d«Ｇ↘³↓²↘³η‖Ｏ¬»h«ＧＨ↖↑→→↑↗↓↘→→↙↓²η‖Ｏ↓».ＧX³ηpＧ↑²↙⁴↖²→⁸↙³↓³→²↓²↖³↙²←³↓²↗²↑³ηsＢ⁹η¿№x+*θ«Ｆ¬⁼θ+ＰX×⁴ηＦ¬⁼θxＰ+×⁵η»«ＧＨ←←←←←↘↓↘↓↘↘↓↘²η‖Ｏ⟲⊗⌕v>^<θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJLTsMwFFwnp7C8cmjoIi0SBIQEFMSCnyoqsUIKidNYMnESO20Q6p4TcApOwVG4SHC@jUPKyk/vM2/eeNzASVzm0Dw/45wsQwR/Pj@gCQLjWOdrItwAoNgA77rrcAwgg7aMtQdG35YsRPacLANhAnvG1mET169VgWhz7FPsivsVTqgTIaX1@0t2bGpsr4fdaZzUK0rUXmFwiQIcKMDXjFK2RvYiusF@QWIRbUm3b5lcRN37hs9UJKgRW6o7BeiwG0t27c1Ze1JVjLrFgpOlbJqWJKvY2nI5VJq24k2U3@ko2mBMlMGi0oewurJYtVAKZS4pn7MMHVVJD/tOSoWta8QH6IKloUAwG@1Jj8VGYSxN81kC0B0T6DJOHcpRbAI4goas3spJEiVEzthPJngkr5ijaQFcCDs4mP0ZHDWDB83gRtcwlVyL5T1X1D/439M1wYAvdqR2lxuf9I1S5ZhwBEYzlr5Q7KErEnoIrk6fTyr9ymM2eT7O91f0Fw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔█η
```

Get the `█` character into a variable. As @ASCII-only explains, a properly encoded Charcoal file would use three bytes to express this character, so it needs to be in a variable as it gets used a lot. (But it's still 2 bytes shorter than the previous approach.)

```
≡θ
```

Use a switch statement for the six easy characters.

```
o«Ｇ→↘→²η‖Ｏ↘¬»
```

Handle the `o` by drawing one eighth of the figure and mirroring it three times.

```
d«Ｇ↘³↓²↘³η‖Ｏ¬»
```

Handle the `d` by drawing one quarter of the figure and mirroring it twice.

```
h«ＧＨ↖↑→→↑↗↓↘→→↙↓²η‖Ｏ↓»
```

Handle the `h` by drawing the top half and mirroring it.

```
.ＧX³η
```

Handle the `.` by drawing a diamond.

```
pＧ↑²↙⁴↖²→⁸↙³↓³→²↓²↖³↙²←³↓²↗²↑³η
```

Handle the `p` by drawing it manually.

```
sＢ⁹η
```

Handle the `s` by drawing a hollow rectangle. (This one is the last of the six because `Box` can take 3 parameters but the following `¿` isn't legal as a parameter.)

```
¿№x+*θ«Ｆ¬⁼θ+ＰX×⁴ηＦ¬⁼θxＰ+×⁵η»
```

Handle the `x`, `+` and `*`, the latter by overlapping the former.

```
«ＧＨ←←←←←↘↓↘↓↘↘↓↘²η‖Ｏ⟲⊗⌕v>^<θ
```

Draw the left half of the `v`, then mirror it, then rotate it if the character happens to be `>`, `^` or `<`.

Comment: Wait, doesn't handle it correctly?

Comment: @ASCII-only: well, that character isn't in Charcoal's code page, so it can't really appear in the source, can it?

Comment: If you check it, it's counted as... 3? bytes. I'm not sure if it actually works, but it should - Charcoal should have rudimentary Unicode translation for a certain number of characters after a `0xFF`. I'll check later and link if it works

Comment: [here](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6CyJCM/z1hBP7@gRD85I7EoOT8xB87QK6hU0NVNSVXQTVZQ0YCpBXLUC4oy80o0lGIq3NyUtJMzijQMkgwNIKDG2FwTLGShqamu@f8/AA)

Comment: @ASCII-only Ah, I didn't know that about the `0xFF` byte. It's a bit confusing because the bytes that the encoded file would need correspond to `�﹪⧴` in Charcoal's code page but TIO works in Unicode characters so you can't easily demonstrate that.

Comment: I'm an idiot and added `�`, it shouldn't actually be there, realized when I was thinking about how the decoding worked - 0xFF will never be translated by itself

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 9 bytes

```
1w&XG7lZG
```

Cheating? Maybe. Try it on [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=1w%26XG7lZG&inputs=%27.%27&version=20.10.0).

Literal translation of the MATLAB code `plot(1,input(''));axis off` (26 bytes). The online version compresses the image, but on a local machine it will simply use the MATLAB plot defaults.

Comment: I guess the consensus is that built-in functions are allowed by default, so no cheating.

Comment: @anatolyg I know, else I wouldn't have posted it. But it definitely _feels_ like cheating ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 58 bytes

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import*
plot(0,input())
axis('off')
```

Fun to take advantage of matplotlib doing all the heavy lifting.